# Datadog extracting value from logs

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

i have the following being output in my logs

```
Finished processing [154976] items for user id [1234]
```

is there any way in datadog i could output that on a widget with

userid -> number

basically process the logs, similar to how we do with errors from logs and creating alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [log processor](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui) with a [grok parser](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/parsing/) rule such as

```
getItemsAndUserid Finished processing [%{integer:count}] items for user id [%{integer:userid}]
```